# WPF window lifecycle

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a newbie in WPF, and need a little help. My question is it safe to do that:

```
var orderWindow = new OrderWindow();
orderWindow.ShowDialog();
var viewModel = orderWindow.ViewModel;
```

Is it's safe to get data from a window after it closed?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, yes. This is safe. You don't risk exceptions.

Long answer. The window class is not destroyed when it closes, it is merely not rendered and so does not participate in any layout passes. This may cause exceptions if you try to perform operations that require the window is displayed.